# Easiest Method to Evaluate $3\times 3$ Determinants

Tags: determinant

After a lot of practice, I developed a method of evaluating $3\times 3$ determinants

which I call the
**Cross - Left Fish - Right Fish**.

[image]

The method goes like this,
for some $3 \times 3$ determinant $\left| A \right|$,
$$\left| \mathbf A \right| 
= \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i\\
\end{array} \right| 
= \overbrace{\left( \color{blue}{aei} - \color{red}{ceg}\right)}^{\text{Cross}} 
+ \overbrace{\left( \color{blue}{dhc} - \color{red}{dbi} \right)}^{\text{Left Fish}}
+ \overbrace{\left( \color{blue}{fbg} - \color{red}{fha} \right)}^{\text{Right Fish}}  
$$
It's easy to remember,even the fish, because the fish consists of ticks.
*In the Left Fish*: The normal tick is positive. The upside down tick is negative.
*In the Right Fish*: The reverse tick is negative. The reverse upside down tick ispositive because two wrongs make a right.

Now, someone had pointed out that they had heard of a similar method and that my idea isn't anything original. Please tell me. Is he right? Is there such a method? Is that method any easier than what I've made?

**What is the easiest method to evaluate determinants?**

Comment: This is well known as the “Sarrus' rule”.

Comment: I havent seen this before, I like it. Ive always just drawn (or imagined) two extra column, that are the same as the first two, so it is 5 wide and 3 tall, and to take the three forward slashes, and minus the three backward slashes, with no strange rules about adding or subtracting.

Comment: This is definitely equivalent to Sarrus's rule, but it is a cute version of it.

Comment: As a polite reminder, these rules unfortunately do not generalize to determinants of $4\times 4$ and larger matrices.

Comment: That's a funny way of representing the Sarrus method, but for higher dimensions you should learn this other method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion

Comment: @Mosk: Don't worry, I know that. My method is quicker though. (Plus, it's cute and mindless)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Rule of Sarrus

[The Rule of Sarrus](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xFIi0JF2AM) is an easy trick equivalent to the Fish/Cross method.

[image: Rule of Sarrus]

Write out the first 2 columns of the matrix to the right of the 3rd column, so that you have 5 columns in a row. Then add the products of the diagonals parallel to the leading diagonal (solid) and subtract the products of the other diagonals with positive slope (dashed).

*Remember:* Add $(-)$ve sloped lines, Subtract $(+)$ve sloped line.

Answer (score 1):

You can take any determinant by looking at the matrix like this,

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a & -b & c \\ -d & e & -f \\ g & -h & i \end{bmatrix}.$$

Now moving down any column or row, strike out all the values across and through it. So if we follow the left column, the first step is.

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x & x & x \\ x & e & -f \\ x & -h & i \end{bmatrix}.$$

So we take the determinant of the matrix left over and multiply it by a, which is $ a \cdot \det \begin{bmatrix} e & -f \\ -h & i \end{bmatrix}.$

Next,

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x & -b & c \\ x & x & x \\ x & -h & i \end{bmatrix},$$

so we now get $ -d \cdot \det\begin{bmatrix} -b & c \\ -h & i \end{bmatrix},$

Then the next step would be

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x & -b & c \\ x & e & -f \\ x & x & x \end{bmatrix},$$

producing

$ g\cdot \det\begin{bmatrix} -b & c \\ e & -f \end{bmatrix}.$

Notice that this follows your method exactly, except you are doing it in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

I always remember the determinant like this:

$$
\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i\\
\end{array} \right|= a\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
e & f\\
h & i\\
\end{array} \right|-b \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
d & f\\
g & i\\
\end{array} \right|+c \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
d & e\\
g & h\\
\end{array} \right|$$

If you look closely, you will see a pattern, but it's difficult to describe it.

From here on, we only have to evaluate $2\times2$ determinants.

Comment: This is the [Laplace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion)

Comment: @Nick not what you were looking for? :) I think it's easier than your method, though..

Comment: The Laplace expansion along $R_1$ is the standard method to evaluate determinants of all orders. It will atleast take 3 to 4 steps to do while my method only takes one if you know how to multiply and subtract properly.