# Show that a determinant is equal to this variable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Show that the :

determinant of:
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&a_{13}\\0&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}

is equal to $-A_{13}A_{22}A_{31}$

I believe the cofactor and submatrix formula is to be used. This is specifically located in the chapter of finding determinants using row reduction! Please keep it simple! Thank you!

Comment: You might want to look at the [rule of Sarrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus)

Comment: Switch rows $1$ and $3$, then your matrix is upper triangular, with determinant $a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}$. Since you did a row switch this is the opposite of the determinant of the original matrix.

Comment: change the rows $1,3$ !

Comment: awesome, that's the answer!!! Thanks guys!! :)

Comment: i  want to give adam hughes or mesel credit whoever posts that first.

Comment: Where you wrote $-A_{13}A_{22}A_{31}$, did you actually mean $-a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}$? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going along the top row, we have

$$0(a_{22}a_{33} - a_{32}a_{23}) - 0(0 - a_{31}a_{23}) + a_{13}(0 - a_{31}a_{22}).$$

See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943136/easiest-method-to-evaluate-3-times-3-determinants/943154#943154) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Expand through first row.